# Как привести строку к числу PHP?

Tags: php

Нужно в поле (int) в MySql вставить число.

Вставляется так:

```
$arFields = Array("RESPONSIBLE_ID" => $manager);

$obTask->Update($arTask["ID"], $arFields);
```

где в переменной $manager число 479 (например).

Но вставляется в поле как 1, т.е., ощущение, что строка вставляется в интовое поле.

Такой вариант

```
(int)$manager
```

и такой

```
(intval)$manager
```

var_dump показывает как array(1) { [0]=> int(479) }, однако все-равно вставляет единицу.

Вот так

```
$arFields = Array("RESPONSIBLE_ID" => 479);
```

все хорошо, вставляется правильно.

Категорически не хочется менять тип поля на строку в БД.

Как побороть данный баг?

```
b_tasks_member | CREATE TABLE `b_tasks_member` (
`TASK_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TYPE` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`TASK_ID`,`USER_ID`,`TYPE`),
  KEY `USER_ID_TYPE` (`USER_ID`,`TYPE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: `show create table` у вашей таблицы покажите

Comment: show create b_tasks_member вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Слово `table` забыли

Comment: @andreymal Добавил

Comment: Стоп-стоп, var_dump показывает array? Ну так тогда просто `$manager[0]`, не?

Comment: @andreymal Таки да)) Спасибо )

Comment: @Leone Так ведь конструкция $arFields = Array("RESPONSIBLE_ID" => 479); работает

Answer (score 0):

Если у вам тут создается массив

```
$arFields = Array("RESPONSIBLE_ID" => $manager);
```

Соответсвенно тут вы должны вызвать значение указав ключ

```
$obTask->Update($arTask["ID"], $arFields["RESPONSIBLE_ID"]);
```

Comment: довольно часто методы а-ля `update` на вход получают ассоциативный массив названий полей и новых значений, что и демонстрируется в данном вопросе. Проблема в том, что `$manager` является массивом, а не числом.

Comment: В вопросе ясно сказано что :где в переменной $manager число 479 (например)."  Соответсвенно это не является массивом

Comment: говорить можно что угодно, var_dump зато приведен, и там явно массив.